# How do I rename desktops in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, applications, spaces, desktop, customization

It seems that Apple doesn't provide a way to rename desktops from the default "Desktop 1", etc. Renaming desktops would be great for my workflow.

Does anyone know how to do this manually or with a third-party app?

Answer (score 2):

If an application is in full screen mode in a given space, that space will have the application's name under it when it is displayed via Mission Control (and you put your mouse cursor over the desktop). Otherwise, I do not believe that there is a way to rename them.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm aware of that functionality but unfortunately what I'm trying to do is to name a 'workspace' on a dual-screen, which has windows from several different applications occupying various parts of the screens. I was hoping there would be a third-party app that could do this.